# to speak / to tell / to talk / to say

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

A thing that really confuses me is the difference between those 4 verbs.

Ok, some cases are really well known and defined (i.e. "*I speak English*", "*How do you say that word?*") but others are confusing.

Let me do some examples:

> (*Interrupting someone*) May I X something?
>
> (*When you don't want to be interrupted*) Let me X !
>
> I X the truth
>
> What I was X is...
>
> I want to X you a thing

Can you choose the correct verb/s for each sentence and explain me some rule?

Also some example would be very appreciate!